# Split Pivoted Index Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivoted data frame that looks like this:

```
                 |Units_sold | Revenue
 -------------------------------------
 California_2015 |     10    |    600   
 California_2016 |     15    |    900
```

There are additional columns, but basically what I'd like to do is unstack the index column, and have my table look like this:

```
 |State     |Year  |Units_sold |Revenue
 -------------------------------------
 California |2015  | 10        |600   
 California |2016  | 15        |900 `
```

Basically I had two data frames that I needed to merge, on the state and year, but I'm just not sure how to split the index column/ if that's possible. Still pretty new to Python, so I really appreciate any input!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Units_sold':[10,15],'Revenue':[600,900]}, index=['California_2015','California_2016'])

df = df.reset_index()
df['State'] = df['index'].str.split("_").str.get(0)
df['Year'] = df['index'].str.split("_").str.get(1)
df = df.set_index('State')[['Year','Units_sold','Revenue']]
df
```